# Change Unity GUI.Box text colour

Tags: user-interface, text, colors, unity-game-engine

I am kind of new to Unity, and was just wondering how to change the text colour of a GUI.Box?

This is the line of code I am using:

```
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, width, height),"Hello World", "");
```

I tried putting:

```
    GUI.color = Color.red;
```

above it, but that didn't work.

Thanks,
Fjpackard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GUI.skin.box.normal.textColor = Color.red;
```

Perhaps a better way is take a look at GUIStyles (http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-GUIStyle.html) since GUIStyle is an easy way to modify the appearance of the whole GUI.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you may want to change only a specific word or sentence, so you just need to make your text like that:

```
sb.Append("<size=10> <color=yellow>WARNING: </color> Some text here</size>");
```

In this case my style font size is 8, so this text will be a bit bigger then the other lines, the word WARNING will be written in yellow and 'Some text here' is the default color. All the other text inside my string builder will use the Box Style

For more details check:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StyledText.html